# Referencing the last page in a PDF with tabula?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula, pdf-scraping

I want to reference the last page from a bunch of PDF documents and parse tables from it, however the number of pages in the documents can vary. What I do know is that the last page is the same for these documents.

```
all_tables_stream = tabula.read_pdf(path, password = password, stream = "True", pages = 'all')
```

Is there an elegant way to do this where I don't have to scrape all pages in the document just to get to the tables on the final page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get the number of pages, for example by using pyPdf

```
import pyPdf
from tabula import read_pdf

reader = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(path, mode='rb' ))
n = reader.getNumPages() 

all_tables_stream = tabula.read_pdf(path, password = password, stream = "True", pages = n)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the same thing. Seems like there is no way to reference the last page with just tabula.